# How to convert text file information to Data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, txt

```
Test case / Scenario:
4.SBI Savings account transaction

Pre-requisities:
Login to the net banking and send money successfully


Steps Description:
First launch the url and click on "Net Banking" button. Now click on "LOGIN" button add_text PERSONAL, Now click on "CONTINUE TO LOGIN" button. You will see a username field there now enter username, enter password and click "Login" button. Now enter one time password or OTP received to your mobile, click "submit" button. Now click on "Payments / Transfers" button, and click on "Quick Transfer (Without Adding Beneficiary)" option. Enter Beneficiary Name, enter Beneficiary Account Number, Re-enter Beneficiary Account Number, select "Within SBI" option, now enter the amount and also choose rent "Rent" option in purpose.Finally accept the terms & conditions by clicking on checkbox.


Test case / Scenario:
5.SBI Savings account transaction

Pre-requisities:
Login to the net banking and send money successfully


Steps Description:
First launch the url and click on "Net Banking" button. Now click on "LOGIN" button add_text PERSONAL, Now click on "CONTINUE TO LOGIN" button. You will see a username field there now enter username, enter password and click "Login" button. Now enter one time password or OTP received to your mobile, click "submit" button. Now click on "Payments / Transfers" button, and click on "Quick Transfer (Without Adding Beneficiary)" option. Enter Beneficiary Name, enter Beneficiary Account Number, Re-enter Beneficiary Account Number, select "Within SBI" option, now enter the amount and also choose rent "Rent" option in purpose.Finally accept the terms and conditions by clicking on checkbox.
```

Now how to convert "Test case / Scenario:", "Pre-requisites", "Steps Description", as Data Frame columns and from "Steps Description" column data should should be split into rows if they have "commas","full-stops","and". How to do I tried and with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


def split_steps_description(data):
    # Find the index of the "Steps Description" heading
    steps_index = data.index("Steps Description:") + 1

    # Get the content under the "Steps Description" heading
    steps_description = data[steps_index].strip()

    # Split the content based on commas, "and," or full stops
    steps = re.split(r',|\sand\s|\.', steps_description)

    # Clean up the steps (remove leading/trailing spaces)
    steps = [step.strip() for step in steps if step.strip()]

    return steps


def text_input(file):
    # Read the text data from a file
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()

    scenarios = []
    current_scenario = None

    for line in data:
        line = line.strip()

        if line.startswith("Test case / Scenario:"):
            current_scenario = line.replace("Test case / Scenario:", "").strip()
        elif line.startswith("Steps Description:"):
            steps = split_steps_description(data)

            # Add each split step as a separate row in the DataFrame
            for step in steps:
                scenarios.append({
                    'Test case / Scenario:': current_scenario,
                    'Steps': step
                })

    # Convert scenarios to DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(scenarios)

    return df


df = text_input('testing.txt')

print(df)
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
Test case / Scenario:                                              Steps
0                                                      First launch the url
1                                             click on "Net Banking" button
2                             Now click on "LOGIN" button add_text PERSONAL
3                                   Now click on "CONTINUE TO LOGIN" button
4                         You will see a username field there now enter ...
5                                                            enter password
6                                                      click "Login" button
7                         Now enter one time password or OTP received to...
8                                                     click "submit" button
9                                Now click on "Payments / Transfers" button
10                        click on "Quick Transfer (Without Adding Benef...
11                                                   Enter Beneficiary Name
12                                         enter Beneficiary Account Number
13                                      Re-enter Beneficiary Account Number
14                                               select "Within SBI" option
15                                                     now enter the amount
16                                also choose rent "Rent" option in purpose
17                        Finally accept the terms & conditions by click...
18                                                     First launch the url
19                                            click on "Net Banking" button
20                            Now click on "LOGIN" button add_text PERSONAL
21                                  Now click on "CONTINUE TO LOGIN" button
22                        You will see a username field there now enter ...
23                                                           enter password
24                                                     click "Login" button
25                        Now enter one time password or OTP received to...
26                                                    click "submit" button
27                               Now click on "Payments / Transfers" button
28                        click on "Quick Transfer (Without Adding Benef...
29                                                   Enter Beneficiary Name
30                                         enter Beneficiary Account Number
31                                      Re-enter Beneficiary Account Number
32                                               select "Within SBI" option
33                                                     now enter the amount
34                                also choose rent "Rent" option in purpose
35                        Finally accept the terms & conditions by click...
```

I'm expecting the output like this:

```
Test case / Scenario:                                              Steps
    0   4.SBI Savings account transaction          First launch the url
    1   4.SBI Savings account transaction          click on "Net Banking" button
    2   4.SBI Savings account transaction          Now click on "LOGIN" button add_text PERSONAL
    3   4.SBI Savings account transaction          Now click on "CONTINUE TO LOGIN" button
```

How to acheive the end results please help me on this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

lines = text.splitlines()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    lines[0]: [lines[1]],
    "Steps": [re.split(r'\.|,|and', lines[5])]
    })

df.explode('Steps')
```